# Bathroom exhaust Fan

Tags: plumbing

I need to install an exhaust fan in my bath on the main floor but I have no place to vent it but down through the basement and out a window.  Is this Okay?

Comment: Is the basement heated? If not, you may get condensation inside the duct. To mitigate that, angle the horizontal section so any water will drain to the outside.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is fine. However, you still want to mount the fan as high as possible to maximize the effectiveness of extracting the warm, moist air. To make installation easier, get a unit rated for wall installation and run the vent straight down to the basement. Also, minimize the number of bends/elbows; ideally only one will be needed.